# Как снова задавать вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, блокировка, заблокированные-вопросы

Я задал на этом сайте всего 2-4 вопроса и лишился возможности их задавать, хотя они были подробными и понятными, и без повторов. Как я могу снова получить возможность задавать вопросы? Стоит ли создать новую учëтную запись?

Comment: Вы бы привели тут ссылки на последние 2 вопроса

Comment: @avp не подумал об этом. Давайте укажу здесь: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1422150/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5](первый вопрос)

Comment: Вопрос как вопрос (на всякий случай плюсанул, вдруг поможет...), только ему уже год. Наверное проблемы с какими-то более поздними. Что конкретно сделать, чтобы исправить ситуацию, я не знаю. Попробуйте попросить совета у кого-то из модераторов.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Всего на сайте вы задали 16 вопросов, из них 4 вопроса имеют отрицательный рейтинг и были удалены либо вами, либо системой. Всего удалено 13 вопросов из 16, из них до удаления было предварительно закрыто 3. Система автоматически заблокировала возможность задавать вопросы, чтобы вы в будущем внимательней отнеслись к их оформлению.

Дополнительную учетную запись с целью обхода блокировок на нашем сайте создавать **запрещено**. Модераторы её заблокируют, а к основной учетной записи в таком случае могут быть применены дополнительные ограничения.

Подробные рекомендации по правильному оформлению вопросов и информацию блокировкам права задавать вопросы можно найти в справке:

- [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Почему блокируются вопросы с моей учетной записи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: И что человеку в такой ситуации делать? Смириться с тем, что он ... (вымарано цензурой) и забить на это сообщество?

Comment: @avp я вижу в справке то же самое, что и вы. _Администрация Stack Exchange не может снять блокировку по просьбе._ - это действительно так. Я вижу что блокировка есть, но снять её технически не смогу, нету кнопочки. Таковы правила работы системы.

Comment: Может пора уже реорганизрвать систему?

Comment: @avp это не от модераторов зависит. Все что можем мы сделать, чтобы разблокировать пользователю возможность задавать вопросы - это оставить положительные голоса на его вопросах.

Comment: @avp если человек настолько оторван от реалий SO - наверное да, забить. ТС говорит что задал 2-4 вопроса, а факты говорят что 16. Интересно, о чем еще ТС умалчивает, сколько предупреждений и временных блокировок он получал? Как именно сформулирована его блокировка сейчас - тоже не говорит.

Comment: @Kromster этот участник не получал предупреждений или блокировок от модераторов. Он не забанен, у него системой заблокирована только возможность задавать вопросы. Отвечать на вопросы он может.

Comment: @aepot слово "бан" я не упоминал )

Comment: *"Модераторы её заблокируют, а к основной учетной записи в таком случае могут быть применены дополнительные ограничения."* --- очень сомнительно. Я 28 мая поставил тревогу на аккаунт человека, обосновал почему аккаунт является мультом. В итоге и первый и второй аккаунты - до сих пор не заблочены. И не смерджены в один (как это обычно делают)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский разбираются. Подождите. Мержить модераторы не могут, только сотрудники.

Comment: @avp, вообще, как я знаю участнику нужно сделать достаточно положительного вклада, чтобы он перевесил отрицательный. У меня как-то в начале использования SO также была убрана возможность задавать вопросы, с того момента я начал писать ответы (с пол. рейтингом) и я снова мог задавать вопросы. По моему, даже где-то был пост по этому поводу либо на нашей, либо на английской Мете, там какая-то формула была.

Comment: @ΝNL993, согласитесь, это не выглядит нормальным, больше похоже на  "научитесь плавать, дадим воду"

Comment: @avp абсолютно точно, именно так оно и чувствовалось когда я получил запрет. Не понимаю как пользователи будут учиться на ошибках, если им не дают делать эти самые ошибки (кстати я сделал намного меньше вопросов плохого качества на тот момент, чем текущий пользователь и всё равно получил запрет).

Comment: @ΝNL993 16 вопросов довольно большое количество, чтобы уже наконец-то разобраться как задавать вопросы :)

Comment: @EzioMercer На момент запрета у меня было примерно 3-5 низкокачественных вопросов (то-есть удалённых (не мной), закрытых и/или с минусом). Это почти в три раза меньше вопросов и я всё равно получил запрет. Ну и как это понимать? (также учитывайте, что на тот момент у меня также был как минимум один вопрос с положительным рейтингом)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Точно так же :) Если 16 - это довольно большое количество, то 5 - это просто достаточное количество, чтобы разобраться как задавать вопросы :)